# Does SpringSource require Internet access to operate?

Tags: spring, xsd, springsource

Silly question perhaps, but a developer group started using SpringSource on systems that were intended to be internal facing systems with no Internet access.  Now these systems talk to springsource.com on port 80 all the time.  This is creating tension with the management who presented to the business that these systems were internal facing and did not access the Internet.

Why does a SpringSource enabled application access springsource.com all the time, and what can be done to control or centralize this access?